# Laptop time active not right

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 running laptop says it has been on for 23 days even though I shut it down every time (not just closing the lid, but normally clicking the windows button and shut it down via the on/off menu item).

[image: Screenshot van windows 10's taskmanager die tijd actief toont.]

Why is this? Is this a bad thing and can I change it?

Sometimes I forget to write down when I start working and try to check it there to see how long I've been on, but that doesn't work in the current situation.

(It's Dutch, check "tijd actief" means "time active")

Comment: Do you shut it fully down or do you use the standard windows quick shutdown. The latter closes userspace programs, but keeps the OS part active.

Comment: @Hennes I just hit Start -> Power -> Shut Down

Comment: I also think you are reading that time wrong.  On my computer, its Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds.  So your computer has been on for 23 hours - not days.

Comment: Can you try this an see of the tijd actief resets? Right click on the windows meu, run, `shutdown /s /t 0`

Comment: @TimmyJim Just checked my w10 install. Last digits are indeed updated once per second.  So yes, potential misread. Good catch. (Stioll, 23h is long to be on, might be a 12 hours yesterday/suspend_kernel/11 hours today thing.

Comment: @Hennes @TimmyJim the time did indeed reset after `shutdown /s /t 0`, and indeed it must be hours instead of days. But still, it for sure hasn't been on for 23 hours...

Comment: Is this option checkmarked on your PC? http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BnnL.png

Comment: @Hennes Yes it is

Comment: Obvious question: Try uncheckmarking it (is that even a word?). Then shutdown and boot a few times.